# Is it possible to use Rime & uIP communication stacks at the same time in Contiki

Tags: contiki

Working on the Contiki - Cooja Simulator, I am wondering how should I use lightweight rime communications stack along with IPv6 based uIP stack.
My main concern is to communicate with minimum overhead between mobile and static nodes in a network and also (in some situations) communicate with IPv6 between mobile nodes and gateway.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, RIME and uIP are two different parts of the netstack, Rime is for radio communications while uIP is a light weight TCP/IP compliant stack. I suggest you go through the documents to understand how exactly they work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with unmodified Contiki.

There is only one global `network_driver` object which normally is either `sicslowpan_driver` or `rime_driver`.

Additionally, in newer versions of Contiki the network stack must be selected at compile time. There are three mutually exclusive options you can set in application's Makefile: `CONTIKI_WITH_RIME`, `CONTIKI_WITH_IPV4`, and `CONTIKI_WITH_IPV6`. For example, this line enables linking the Rime library with your application:

```
CONTIKI_WITH_RIME = 1
```